# How can I make the logo line up with the navigation links in the Navbar section?

Tags: html, css

I cannot seem to find a way to make my logo line up with the navigation links on my website. The navigation links and the logo are in the correct alignment, but there is too much space below the logo, and too much space above the navigation links preventing them from being in-line with each other. See attached screenshot of the website. [example of problem on the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BL7ok.png).

This is my code for the css:

```
#navbar{
  text-align: left; 
}

.topnav{
  
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: solid rgb(30, 128, 255);
  border-bottom: solid rgb(30, 128, 255);
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 100%;
    /*overflow: auto;*/
    /*margin: auto;*/
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1.75%;
  padding-bottom: .75%;
}



.topnav a {
  /*float: left;*/
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 20%;
}
```

This is the corresponding HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="topnav">
    <div id="navbar"><a href="index.html"><img src="Images\christopher-avallon-high-resolution-logo-transparent.png" height="50px" width="auto"></a></div>
    <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="about.html">About Me</a>
    <a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
    <a href="#about">Contact</a>
    <!--<input type="text" placeholder="Search..">-->
  </div>

  <div id="description" class="header">
  <h1>Data Science & Engineering</h1>
    <p><h4>This is a personal website I created to showcase my experience and past projects to you. </h4></p>

    </div>

<br>
```

I tried adding display: inline-block; to the css in two sections, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Paragraphs cannot contain headings, it's invalid HTML

Answer (score 0):

Currently the logo and the navigation links are in display block, so they are placed vertically.

- To align the logo and navigation links horizontally, you can use the following CSS modifications:

  ```
  .topnav {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      /* Add any other styles you need */
  }
  ```
- And you should add `display: block;` to the image inside the `#navbar`. (To eliminate a small gap below the image)
- And consider changing the css selector `.topnav a` to `.topnav > a`, to only target direct children of `.topnav` (i.e. every `a` tag except the one containing the logo)

At the end your code should look like:

```
.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: solid rgb(30, 128, 255);
    border-bottom: solid rgb(30, 128, 255);
    font-family: Arial;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1.75%;
    padding-bottom: .75%;
    display: flex;  /* New */
    align-items: center;  /* New */
}

#navbar {
    text-align: left;
}

#navbar img {
    display: block;  /* New */
}

.topnav > a {  /* New */
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 20%;
}
```